# Glossaries-extra alttree style: increase horizontal spacing

Tags: spacing, glossaries-extra

I successfully use `glossaries-extra` style `alltree` to automatically align my list of abbreviations and symbols depending on the widest element. Now, I'd like to increase the horizontal spacing by e.g. 2mm between DFT and discrete Fourier transform without breaking `\glsfindwidesttoplevelname[abbreviations,symbols]`. Is this possible or is a table style more suitable? Thanks!

[image: Default spacing]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
10pt,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Glossaries
\usepackage[abbreviations,symbols,nonumberlist,nogroupskip]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries[abbreviations,symbols]

% No glossary title
\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
\setglossarypreamble[abbreviations]{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\setglossarypreamble[symbols]{\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}

% Glossaries style
\setglossarystyle{alttree}
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\normalfont{#1}}

% Abbreviations
\newabbreviation{fem}{FEM}{finite element method}
\newabbreviation{dft}{DFT}{discrete Fourier transfom}

% Symbols
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Fourier series constant component multiplier}]{a0}{a\textsubscript{0}}

\glsaddallunused % Print all entries including uncited ones
\glsfindwidesttoplevelname[abbreviations,symbols] % Automatically find widest element

\begin{document}

\chapter{List of Abbreviations and Symbols}
\section{Abbreviations}

\printglossary[type=abbreviations]

\section{Symbols}

\printglossary[type=symbols]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did yo solve the problem? I want to do the same :(

Comment: @EduardoJiménez No, unfortunately not